# Exclude nested model field in django serializer

Tags: python, django, web

So I have two django models but one of them has a field I need to exclude called code. I haven't found a way to exclude this field using the serializer class.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    modelBs = models.ManyToManyField('ModelB')

class ModelB(models.Model):
    # assume all sorts of fields here like name, location, etc..
    code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

My issue is I can't exclude the modelB code when serializing model A like so:

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        exclude = ('modelBs__code')
```

The serializer above does not work. Anyone know how to go about this?

My current output is:

```
[
    {
        modelBs: [
                     {name: "Something", code: "XXXX"}
                 ]
    }
]
```

My desired output is:

```
    [
        {
            modelBs: [
                         {name: "Something"}
                     ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What is the current `ModelASerializer` serialized data looks like?

Comment: @SachinKukreja What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `ModelASerializer(modelA_obj).data`?

Comment: Its a conceptual model e.g

{modelBs: [{name: 'something', code: 'XXXX'},...]}

Comment: Edit the question and add the output that you get right now and the output you wish to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the exclude in `ModelBSerializer`.

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    modelBs = ModelBSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        ...

class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        ...
        exlude = ("code",)
```

Comment: **Sorted!** Thanks a lot!